# Unable to reproduce Material Lite js demo: Hamburger icon does not appear

Tags: material-design

Working with Material Design Lite, and the initial test is proving unreliable. I'm trying to reproduce the demo shown here: [The first Layout Example](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section).

It looks like this, a menu header with a hamburger icon: [image: screenshot from MLD]. However when I try to implement this in my project I get the header with the "Title" text, but no Hamburger Icon. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<head>
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="images/android-desktop.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.cyan-light_blue.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="demo-layout-transparent mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-layout__header--transparent">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <!-- Title -->
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link1</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link2</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <main class="mdl-layout__content">
  </main>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

There's no explicit mention of the menu icon and I believe that is because the default is for it to appear although the documentation is unclear on this point.

Here's the code they list to use for this demo to work:

```
<style>
.demo-layout-transparent {
  background: url('../assets/demos/transparent.jpg') center / cover;
}
.demo-layout-transparent .mdl-layout__header,
.demo-layout-transparent .mdl-layout__drawer-button {
  color: white;
}
</style>

<div class="demo-layout-transparent mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-layout__header--transparent">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
      <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
      <nav class="mdl-navigation">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <main class="mdl-layout__content">
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="mdl-layout__drawer-button" 
role="button" aria-expanded="false">
   <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
</div>
```

add this between these two divs `mdl-layout__drawer`, `mdl-layout__content`

Comment: That did work, but can you explain why and why the demo on the website does not have this content? Thank you!

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xErgXJ here's working demo with just one change blue background color instead of  image. And one more thing you forget to add JS file in code snippet above. Oops i  read did not instead of did the reason they don't show such things is they  just want to show essential parts of the code. (only if you are really new to HTML and CSS otherwise ignore it) you can inspect element in any browser and see HTML. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/